# Finding optimal set of permutations

Tags: permutations, discrete-mathematics

I have the following data set of a human population. The data set captures households and relationships of the persons living in those households. My problem is how to group the individuals into households to get the optimal set of household configurations (permutations)

Following is an excerpt from my contingency table.

```
       RnC  RU15c RO15c RUO15c   SA  SU15c SO15c SUO15c Chld  Total
HH1     22     17    38      7   11      1     0      0    0     96
HH2     45     35    76     15   22      1     1      0   40    235
HH3     41     31    69     13   19      1     1      0   36    211
Total  108     83   183     35   52      3     2      0   76    542

HH1 = household with only one member
HH2 = household with only two members

Rnc = An adult person in a marital relationship and has no children
RU15c = An adult person in a marital relationship and has age under 15 children
RO15c= An adult person in a marital relationship and has age over 15 children
RUO15c = An adult person in a marital relationship and has over 15 children and under 15 children 
SA = single adult person (age over 15 persons) 
SU15c = Single adult person who has under 15 children 
Chld    = Child (Under 15)


HH1,RnC = 22 This means that there are 22 persons who are 'in a martial relationship and has no children' living alone

HH3,RnC = 19 This means that there are 19 persons who are in a relationship that are part of a 3 member households (Following is a possible permutation An adult (RnC) living with her father (RO15c) and mother (RO15c) ). 

Persons who are in relationships may not live with their partner. Under 15 children must always live with at least one adult (parent)
```

This is bit similar to knapsack problem, but I am dealing with multiple knapsacks that are of different sizes.

I understand that there are multiple correct household configurations. My objective is finding one of these correct ones.

My question is, are there any known mathematical approaches for solving this type of problems?

Comment: If you believe the off-topic reason for closure is in error, then you can try to make an appeal in this thread: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-votes It might help if you explain in more detail why this is a matter of interest for research mathematicians, mentioning the knapsack problem etc. If nothing else, it might garner some suggestions about a good place to submit your inquiry (if not MO).